# Get all connected clients to the broker - emqttd

Tags: mqtt

I am working on IoT implementation in my current project. I have setup my MQTT broker using emqttd. Is there a way in which I can find what are the clients connected to each other with the same topic.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

The MQTT protocol does not directly support this type of thing.

Any support would be specific to the broker that you are using.

You may find stats on how many clients are connected available under the *$SYS* topic tree.

And looking at the emqtt page suggests that you may be able to get connected clients by using the [Presence](https://github.com/emqtt/emqttd/wiki/Presence) plugin, but not what topics they are subscribed to.